# Why class style isn't being applied to button

Tags: jquery, css

Any comment on why the CSS classes are not being applied to the buttons with the JQuery I have when they are pressed?

CSS

```
input[type=button] {
    width: 100px;
    &.is-pressed {
        border: 5px solid blue; }
    &.is-not-pressed {
        border: none; }
}
```

JQuery

```
$(":button").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("input[type=button].is-pressed")
    .removeClass("input[type=button].is-not-pressed");

    $(':button').not(this).each(function(){
         $(this).addClass("input[type=button].is-not-pressed");
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzLjd/7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your style sheet is not CSS, it looks like you have a LESS script, you need to parse it for the CSS styles to get applied.

Also your script is not proper, when you add a class only the class name need to be specified not all the selector that was specified in the css rule

```
$(":button").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("is-pressed")
        .removeClass("is-not-pressed");

    $('.is-pressed:button').not(this).addClass("is-not-pressed").removeClass("is-pressed");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mLmBv/)

Comment: don't even need a "is-not-pressed" class too.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. You're not using the pre-compiled css. And if you add class in jQuery you don't have to add the `.` inside.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EzLjd/8/)

**jQuery**

Change this:

```
 $(this).addClass("input[type=button].is-pressed")
    .removeClass("input[type=button].is-not-pressed");
```

To this:

```
    $(this).addClass("is-pressed")
    .removeClass("is-not-pressed");
```

And compile your
**CSS** to this.

```
input[type=button] {
    width: 100px;
}
input[type=button].is-pressed {
        border: 5px solid blue; 
}
input[type=button].is-not-pressed {
        border: none; 
}
```